'Add Friend' button not displayed for account I recently unblocked
I recently unblocked a friend of mine's profile on Facebook and want to send him a friend request but the "Add friend" button is missing.  I can still see the "Follow" button.
He didn't change his privacy settings and we had 85 mutual friends. I've reported this to Facebook but have been waiting more than 10 days.
Try updating application. Try another device.
